# How to check out DHCP lease time on OpenSUSE provided by DHCP server

Tags: opensuse, dhcp

I need to check out DHCP lease time on OpenSUSE Leap 42.2, I tried these, but they didn't work:

```
~> less /etc/dhclient.conf
~> sudo less /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases
# ls -a /var/lib/NetworkManager/
~> sudo ifconfig -a
```

How can I do that?

---

I run the following command as suggested by @MariusMatutiae:

```
linux-box:/var/log # grep -nriIl dhc

YaST2/mkinitrd.log
YaST2/macro_inst_initial.ycp
YaST2/y2log
zypp/history
audit/audit.log
pk_backend_zypp-1
pk_backend_zypp
zypper.log
boot.log
```

Then I do the following for each output file, but I couldn't find the **lease time** provided by DHCP.

```
linux-box:/var/log # grep -E "dhc" YaST2/y2log
```

Answer (score 1):

The lease time is stored in one of the */var/log* files, but which one depends on distro. The following command

```
 cd /var/log && grep -nriIl dhclient
```

finds all files mentioning *dhclient*, and in my case (Debian) it is clear that the file is *syslog*:

```
# grep -nirIl dhclient
installer/syslog
syslog
syslog.1
kern.log.1
audit/audit.log.4
audit/audit.log.2
audit/audit.log.1
audit/audit.log.3
```

Then I get:

```
# grep dhclient syslog
Jul  4 08:30:23 hague dhclient[1357]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.73.66 on eth0 to 192.168.73.1 port 67 (xid=0x7251b5d5)
Jul  4 08:30:23 hague dhclient[1357]: DHCPACK of 192.168.73.66 from 192.168.73.1
Jul  4 08:30:23 hague dhclient[1357]: bound to 192.168.73.66 -- renewal in 18682 seconds.
Jul  4 13:41:45 hague dhclient[1357]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.73.66 on eth0 to 192.168.73.1 port 67 (xid=0x7251b5d5)
Jul  4 13:41:45 hague dhclient[1357]: DHCPACK of 192.168.73.66 from 192.168.73.1
Jul  4 13:41:45 hague dhclient[1357]: bound to 192.168.73.66 -- renewal in 14622 seconds.
```

which gives the answer you are searching for.

Comment: I did `# cd /var/log/ && grep -nriIl dhclien`, the output is `YaST2/y2log`
and `audit/audit.log`. However, `# grep dhclient YaST2/y2log` returns nothing and `# grep dhclient audit/audit.log` returns: `type=USER_CMD msg=audit(1499168810.664:1514): pid=5925 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='cwd="/home/mydear" cmd="dhclient" terminal=pts/3 res=success'`

Comment: @user3405291 Try using *dhc* instead of *dhclient*, you may have *dhcpcd* running instead of *dhclient*.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
less /var/lib/dhcp/db/dhcpd.leases
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. However, it would appear that the OP is trying to find out the lease time on the _client_ machine, indicating that no access to the server is available/granted. You may want to add a few words of explanation concerning that issue.